# C++ ofstream vs basic_ofstream

Tags: c++11

I am confusion.

I'm learning about the ofstream, it seems that it's really a basic_ofstream according to:

- https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ofstream/basic_ofstream
- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7z434859.aspx

What is the reason for a class named basic_ofstream with a constructor named ofstream? 'basic' implies that there is a non-basic version. Why is the constructor name different than the class name?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no constructor named `ofstream` (constructors don't have names), and there's no class named `basic_ofstream` (despite of what Microsoft documentation claims).

`basic_ofstream` is a *class template* (which is different from a class), and `ofstream` is a *`typedef` name* a.k.a. *type alias* that refers to one instantiation of that template, specifically to `basic_ofstream<char>`.

`wofstream` is another such name that refers to `basic_ofstream<wchar_t>`.

This is the naming convention that the C++ standard library uses to define different variants of types that differ in the character type they use. Another set of names that follows this convention is `basic_string`, `string` and `wstring`.

Answer (score 2):

This is not constructor named differently. It's a specialization. So `basic_ofstream` is a template. Then you have two "shortcut names":

```
ofstream    for basic_ofstream<char>
wofstream   for basic_ofstream<wchar_t>
```

Why are they named basic... maybe because standard library provides only basic versions and client can write non-basic classes and plug them in. If you look at [c++ standard io library diagram](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io), all components are prefixed as "basic".

It's usually by replacing `basic_streambuf` any tying custom `streambuf` to `stream`. One example taken from boost

```
#include <ostream>
#include <boost/iostreams/device/file.hpp>
#include <boost/iostreams/stream.hpp>

namespace io = boost::iostreams;

int main()
{
    io::stream_buffer<io::file_sink> buf("log.txt");
    std::ostream                     out(&buf);
    // out writes to log.txt
}
```

It's a buffer implementation working with `std::ostream`.

If you want to explore fancy implementations you can checkout more from [`boost::iostreams`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_67_0/libs/iostreams/doc/index.html) library and their examples. Nice one is with gzip. It works with `ifstream`:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/iostreams/filtering_streambuf.hpp>
#include <boost/iostreams/copy.hpp>
#include <boost/iostreams/filter/gzip.hpp>

int main() 
{
    using namespace std;

    ifstream file("hello.gz", ios_base::in | ios_base::binary);
    filtering_streambuf<input> in;
    in.push(gzip_decompressor());
    in.push(file);
    boost::iostreams::copy(in, cout);
}
```